# Testing custom redux middleware

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

How do I unit test custom redux middleware? I have this simple function that is supposed to dispatch action after a given timeout but ... I have no idea how to approach it. I dint find enough resources regarding this issue.

```
const callAPiTimeoutMiddleware = store => next => (action) => {
  if (action[CALL_API]) {
    if (action[CALL_API].onTimeout) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        store.dispatch({ type: action[CALL_API].onTimeout });
      }, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_LENGTH);
    }
  }

  return next(action);
}
```

**These are my tests based on blog post that is mentioned in the accepted answer:**

```
describe('callAPiTimeoutMiddleware', () => {
  describe('With [CALL_API] symbol', () => {
    it('should dispatch custom action', () => {
      const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
      const fakeStore = { dispatch: sinon.spy() };
      const fakeNext = sinon.spy();
      const fakeAction = {
        [CALL_API]: {
          endpoint: 'endPoint',
          method: 'METHOD',
          types: ['REQUEST_TYPE', 'SUCCESS_TYPE', 'FAILURE_TYPE'],
          onTimeout: 'TIMEOUT_TYPE',
        },
      };

      callAPiTimeoutMiddleware(fakeStore)(fakeNext)(fakeAction);
      clock.tick(99000);

      expect(fakeStore.dispatch.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
    });


    it('should call next action', () => {
      const fakeStore = { dispatch: sinon.spy() };
      const fakeNext = sinon.spy();
      const fakeAction = {
        [CALL_API]: {
          endpoint: 'endPoint',
          method: 'METHOD',
          types: ['REQUEST_TYPE', 'SUCCESS_TYPE', 'FAILURE_TYPE'],
          onTimeout: 'TIMEOUT_TYPE',
        },
      };

      callAPiTimeoutMiddleware(fakeStore)(fakeNext)(fakeAction);

      expect(fakeNext.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
    });
  });

  describe('Without [CALL_API] symbol', () => {
    it('should NOT dispatch anything', () => {
      const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
      const fakeStore = { dispatch: sinon.spy() };
      const fakeNext = sinon.spy();
      const fakeAction = { type: 'SOME_TYPE' };

      callAPiTimeoutMiddleware(fakeStore)(fakeNext)(fakeAction);
      clock.tick(99000);

      expect(fakeStore.dispatch.calledOnce).toEqual(false);
    });


    it('should call next action', () => {
      const fakeStore = { dispatch: sinon.spy() };
      const fakeNext = sinon.spy();
      const fakeAction = { type: 'SOME_TYPE' };

      callAPiTimeoutMiddleware(fakeStore)(fakeNext)(fakeAction);

      expect(fakeNext.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It is a function - what about usual unit-test luncher such as Mocha, AVA, Jasmine etc. and mock-builder like Sinon or manual mock for store?

Comment: I don't really know how to use those. :( Could you please show me working example?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `redux-thunk` middleware has unit tests written. You can refer that [here](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/blob/master/test/test.ts)

He is using only mocha and chai.

And [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html) he is talking about how you can write unit tests for your redux app.

Nice [blog](http://jonnyreeves.co.uk/2016/redux-middleware/) on redux middlewares and how to write unit tests for them.

Answer (score 10):

I needed some more details to actually create tests for the middleware, so here is my answer specific to the middleware test:

Middlewares can be tested very easily without doing a lot of mocking. The chained arrow functions appear intimidating, but it is just a matter of how they are called. I used jest to help me testing but you can replace all jest functions with something else. I'll get right into the code and explain in comments:

```
import logger from './logger'; //this is your middleware
const next = jest.fn(); // middleware needs those as parameters, usually calling next(action) at the end to proceed
const store = jest.fn(); 

const action = { type: 'YOUR_ACTION_TYPE', payload: { your: 'data' }}
logger(store)(next)(action);
```

This is how you call your middleware in a test. In your case if you want to check if dispatch has been called you could do something like this:

```
// Add this in the beginning
store.dispatch = jest.fn();

// Add this after calling logger()
expect(store.dispatch.mock.calls).toEqual('whatever calls you expected');
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: is there any more direct way to test it instead of mocking every function that returned by the middleware?